# How to determine if PHP-to-Solr connection is slow?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, lamp, solr

Hi have a LAMP stack connecting to a Solr 3.6.1 server running on CentOS 6.3. While benchmarking my app, I noticed sudden spikes in the time taken for PHP to send a search query to Solr and getting the results back.

This time is usually about 20-40 msec and Solr's `QTime` is typically 0-30 msec.

**My benchmark results:**

```
Start function                                         msec
Creating the query                                     2.50196456909 msec
Executing query and getting results (PHP & Solr)       37.4531745911 msec
    \->Executing query (as reported by Solr QTime)     21 msec
Processing Solr results
```

**Problem:** However, sometimes this step `Executing query and getting results (PHP & Solr)` will shoot up to 2000+ msec, and Solr continues reporting 0-30msec `QTime`. This makes me suspect that there may be a problem in the connections between PHP/Apache and Solr.

How can I determine if this is true, or make this connection better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `curl` to replicate a search request
2. Loop `curl` and see if you get the same response times
3. Run the loop at the same time as hitting the PHP app and see if there's disparity.
4. Use Wireshark/tcpdump to check what is happening to the socket connection